# In BlackBerry 10 how can I read a QML object's property from the C++ code?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I know how to make a propertyalias in the QML

```
property alias workisvis: blahblah.visible
```

and then *set* a property for it using

```
root->setProperty(workisvis,false)
```

from my C++ code. But how do I *read* a property of a QML object from my C++ code? Something like "getProperty" (I tried that but it didn't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost getProperty:

root->property("workisvis").toBool();